# Restrict core to generate taxonomy terms' URLs

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I'm working on very large existing Drupal site that has thousands of nodes, user in it and bunch of Taxonomies as well.

I understand very well that Drupal core generates default URLs `(taxonomy/term/tid)` as we create a taxonomy term but my requirement is not to so is there a way we can control it?

**Updated**

Actually, I'm working on SEO of the site so according to the SEO report there are more than 10K redirections **to** `404 page` **from** the `Location taxonomy term pages` (URL aliases generated by [pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/pathauto) module and redirected by custom code to 404). So the owners want to reduce 404 redirections.

I was thinking I can achieve this

- By deleting URL aliases of terms so aliases URLs'll not be listed in the google search (would be less SEO friendly) and user'll not try to access, by this way we can reduce 404 redirection.
- By deleting `taxonomy/term/tid`, path to such terms will permanently removed so I'll also help to reduce 404.

What do you suggest?

Comment: Can you explain little more about this and what you tried to acheive this

Comment: Core doesn't generate any URLs, there's a route listening for a pattern matching `/taxonomy/term/tid`. Removing that route would probably cause problems, maybe your best approach would be to deny access to those pages. You can do that easily with the Rabbit Hole module, or with a route subscriber in code

Comment: Can't path auto module help you with changing the urls to a new url alias?

Comment: @AjayReddy , see updated question.

Comment: @Clive, see updated question and please suggest an idea

Comment: I recommend the same as my original idea. If you don't want the URLs to get into Google, simply don't link to them anywhere. Google can't find the pages if you don't link to them (and don't include them in a sitemap). For URLs that are already in Google, maybe serve a more accurate status code like 410. Your SEO advisor will be able tell you the best approach for that

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this previously has been to ensure that there are no links within the site to taxonomy terms and that they are removed from the XML sitepath (using https://www.drupal.org/project/xmlsitemap) so they don't get into the search engines' database in the first place.

I would also recommend a module such as https://www.drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole which can force either a redirect, page not found, or access denied for taxonomy pages (and others) automatically.

I don't think there's any sense in trying to remove taxonomy links from the system when you can use the modules above to achieve this automatically for you.